# how to replace Math.random() function with another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random

I want to generate the numbers randomly in a secured way.

I have been using the `Math.random()` previously like in the code

```
url += "abixmlrequest=true&abi_rand=" + Math.random();
```

The Function is not supported in IE it seems.

```
window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
```

I need to use any other function that is supported in Internet Explorer.
suggest some other Function to generate a random number in a easier way and also secured.

Comment: @Josh Beam   I Need a function to replace Math.random() , which is suppoerted in IE. I couldnt find such thing to my knowlwdge. Any help is appreciated. Thanks